# Gatsby: How to display a list of images specified in a yaml file?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I use the current version of Gatsby (2.x) and want to use gatsby-image for rendering a gallery for products.

I have several YAML files for products. I can already create pages with the text content of these files but I also want to add a small gallery with images specified in the `.yaml` file.

An example YAML file looks like this:

```
product: "Some product"
description: "It is really awesome!"
screenshots:
  - /img/product1/screenshot1.jpg
  - /img/product1/screenshot2.jpg
  - /img/product1/screenshot3.jpg
```

My problem now is that I can get the screenshots only as strings but I have no idea how to pass them to  for rendering.

I thought of creating a component that takes the file name and uses a query to get the image data - but it can't take any parameters because it can only use static queries.

I've also not found a way to pass results from the first graphql query to a second for the image data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install gatsby-transformer-sharp and gatsby-plugin-sharp and use a correct path to your images, Gatsby will automatically pick those up and pipe them through sharp, hence you can query those images. You can have a look at one of my sites which also uses a YML file with image paths that I then use with gatsby-image: https://github.com/LekoArts/gatsby-starter-portfolio/blob/master/src/sites/sites.yaml

Comment: Thanks - that really helped. The issue was that the relative path was wrong: The screenshots showed up as strings. With the path fixed they are now files and have the childImageSharp that was missing before.